# Issues after updating Nexus 4 to Android Lollipop

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop

I am observing the following behavior after upgrading (flash and upload factory image, no OTA) my Nexus 4 to Android Lollipop.

1. When I clear all the recents, and again try to view recents, I am
   still able to see apps over there (most of the times, I see `Android System` )
2. Battery is draining very fast.
3. Battery charging speed is drastically reduced.
4. While trying to call from the `Speed Dial` tab, the call screen comes up after a while. I kept on tapping the contact but the call was already started in the background.

Is it currently possible to install/update to Android Lollipop on the Nexus 4 without these being an issue? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, I have been hearing about it, I have seen people over the forums talking that the performance of the system was greatly reduced after the update and all, which makes me think that you aren't the only one having problems. I don't think there's much you can do other than waiting for the bug fix update to arrive.

Comment: Yeah I updated it today and I m facing the same problem. They should have tested it out on device before rolling out updates.

Comment: It sounds like the update is generally buggy. You could try a factory reset in case your old data is causing issues. With that said, I think there's too much going on here to be properly addressed in one question.

Answer (score 2):

I did a factory reset and its working fine now. May be there was a problem in upgrading.

Comment: Even I had flashed. No OTA.